# Counting records SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to count the number of records for each user:

```
SELECT count(userID) as countOfRecords FROM (select distinct userID from `table`)
```

I get the error: *Every derived table must have its own alias* What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it in SQL Server ?

Comment: Your correct query in syntax is : `SELECT count(userID) as countOfRecords FROM (select distinct tbl.userID from 'table' As tbl) As dt `; but your answer is below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY`

```
select userID, count(*) as countOfRecords
from table
group by userID
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a derived table, you can just do count(distinct):

```
SELECT count(distinct userID) as countOfRecords
FROM `table`
```

**Edit:** When I see Philip Fourie's answer I realize I perhaps didn't give the complete answer... See his `GROUP BY` solution as well.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read carefully enough, so I did just give you a half answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness and because MySql was not tagged explicitly. If you use SQL-Server you could also use [`COUNT(*) OVER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx). Then you get the number of records for each `UserID` **in every row**:

```
SELECT userID,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITON BY userID) AS countOfRecords, 
       other columns ...
FROM dbo.TableName
```